# Where Clause Return Null Record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I am not sure this is possible, but here is what I am trying to do: In the where clause below it is working fine but now I need to somehow:

If @Contact has a value of 'Steve' but 'Steve' does not exist in contact I want to return records where contact is null.

How can I achieve that?

```
WHERE (contact =  @Contact OR (contact IS NULL AND @Contact IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 3):

One method uses a subquery.  A version that doesn't use a subquery is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
where contact = @Contact or contact is null
order by contact desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit on exactly what you are after, but one possibility might be something like this?

```
select * from someTable t
where 1 = 
   (case when exists(select * from someTable t2 where t2.contact = @contact) 
    then 
        case when @contact = t.contact then 1 end
    else 
        case when t.contact IS NULL then 1 end
    end)
```

This means:

IF at least one row exists in someTable, where someTable.contact = @contact, 
then return all rows where someTable.contact = @contact .
Otherwise, return all rows where someTable.contact IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up as a stored procedure, you can set the default to a blank and then use that in the WHERE statement.  Below is a pseudo-example from a working proc.  It uses a [Full-Text Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql) but you get the idea.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procMyProc]

      @p_searchtermKeyword NVARCHAR(255) = '""'

  AS
  BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ((CONTAINS(Keywords, @p_searchtermKeyword)) OR  @p_searchtermKeyword = '""') 

  END
```